# Maintain order in .groupBy() operation of Scala collection

Tags: scala

I have the following code snippet:

```
object Main1 extends App {
  sealed trait XYZ
  {
    def id : String
  }
  class Test() extends XYZ {
    override def id: String = "Test"
  }
  class ABC() extends XYZ {
    override def id: String = "ABC"
  }
  val a: List[XYZ] = List(new Test(), new ABC())
  val b: Map[String, List[XYZ]] = a.groupBy(_.id)
  println(b)

  val c: List[XYZ] = List(new ABC(), new Test())
  val d: Map[String, List[XYZ]] = c.groupBy(_.id)
  println(d)
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Map(Test -> List(Main1$Test@7dc5e7b4), ABC -> List(Main1$ABC@1ee0005))
Map(Test -> List(Main1$Test@3d012ddd), ABC -> List(Main1$ABC@6f2b958e))
```

How can I maintain the order in the result like in the input collection?

Comment: Why does the order matters for you? **Maps** are unordered collections by design. There are of course some ordered variants, but they usually come with a performance penalty on their lookup operation, which is the only reason for using a **Map**. If you do not need lookup and just want an ordered list of list grouped by their id, you can get that result using a simple `foldLeft`

Comment: The real issue was the change in the behavior of `.groupBy()` function in Scala 2.12 and Scala 213. Due to upgrade, the response of the `.groupBy()` changed and to keep the response in line with the legacy system, I wanted to maintain the order.

Comment: Again, why did you need that? **Maps** are not ordered, `groupBy` does not guarantee any order. If your code relay on unspecified behaviour you will have problems, since maintainers are free to change those semantics.

Comment: Agreed, that's why we removed the ordering criteria. Now the ordering is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not limited to use immutable collections only then it can be easily done with `mutable.LinkedHashMap`:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object Main1 extends App {
  sealed trait XYZ
  {
    def id : String
  }
  class Test() extends XYZ {
    override def id: String = "Test"
  }
  class ABC() extends XYZ {
    override def id: String = "ABC"
  }
  val a: List[XYZ] = List(new Test(), new ABC())
  val b: mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, ArrayBuffer[XYZ]] = a.foldLeft(mutable.LinkedHashMap.empty[String, ArrayBuffer[XYZ]]) { (m, x) =>
    m.getOrElseUpdate(x.id, new ArrayBuffer[XYZ]) += x
    m
  }
  println(b)

  val c: List[XYZ] = List(new ABC(), new Test())
  val d: mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, ArrayBuffer[XYZ]] = c.foldLeft(mutable.LinkedHashMap.empty[String, ArrayBuffer[XYZ]]) { (m, x) =>
    m.getOrElseUpdate(x.id, new ArrayBuffer[XYZ]) += x
    m
  }
  println(d)
}
```

Output maintains the order of the input collection:

```
LinkedHashMap(Test -> ArrayBuffer(com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.examples.Main1$Test@56cbfb61), ABC -> ArrayBuffer(com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.examples.Main1$ABC@1134affc))
LinkedHashMap(ABC -> ArrayBuffer(com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.examples.Main1$ABC@1b0375b3), Test -> ArrayBuffer(com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.examples.Main1$Test@2f7c7260))
```